# Cross domain: the cache manifest itself

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache

I recently embarked on building a web application that runs completely offline on mobile devices.

Our set up was this:

- The CMS and API run off an EC2 server on a domain A;
- The assets are published to a S3 bucket on domain B;
- The web app is hosted on a S3 static website bucket on domain C.

I'm not able to cross domain the cache manifest itself (since it is a dynamic file its location cannot be changed).

How can I cache the file without being the cache.manifest file location changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#h-content-security-policy) cross-domain is allowed with the manifest:

> The manifest-src and default-src directives govern the origins from which a user agent can fetch a manifest. As with other directives, by default the manifest-src directive is *, meaning that a user agent can, [CORS] permitting, fetch the manifest cross-domain. Remote origins (e.g., a CDN) wanting to host manifests for various web applications will need to include the appropriate [CORS] response header in their HTTP response (e.g., Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com).

You can check if the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is present with the manifest.  For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
[...]
```

Comment: it says  about crossdomain asset file in manifest file,not crossdomain of manifest file

Comment: That's the best reference I can find on W3C. Can you share the response headers of the `manifest.json`? If you don't see the header I mentioned, CORS can be [configured](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) on S3.

Comment: i mean my cache.manifest file is on server A and my html page on serverC.i am fetching manifest file using <html manifest="location/cache.manifest">

Comment: What server is on EC2? I'd Google "<server technology> CORS" and add the CORS header for the `manifest.json`.

Comment: am not using manifest.json anywhere.server name is just example

Comment: Not sure why I said `manifest.json`, I meant to say `location/cache.manifest` :)

Comment: Great, you've found the problem. Good luck in enabling CORS for this (it may be quite some work if it's across many servers in the system). Anyway, over and out. :)

Comment: it seems to be not the actual solution,Thank you for the tip